# Receiving "Uncaught TypeError: this.props.parentCallback2 is not a function" while trying to pass data between 2 childs to parent

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, react-props

I am quite new to ReactJS and I am trying to make a Trello Clone. I have linked my GitHub page with my code below since its to much to put on here.

My problem is I am receiving the error "`Uncaught TypeError: this.props.parentCallback2 is not a function`" when trying to pass data back to the parent from the child component.

I have tried re-writing the code multiple ways and Googling around to try and find a answer but no luck. My end goal is to make it so that when you click on an item, it makes the "`<ModifyModal />`" appear on the screen.

Below is my code:

[App.js file](https://github.com/BlazingIsFire/Trello-Clone2/blob/main/src/App.js)
[Toolbox.jsx file](https://github.com/BlazingIsFire/Trello-Clone2/blob/main/src/Todobox.jsx)
[Item.jsx file](https://github.com/BlazingIsFire/Trello-Clone2/blob/main/src/Item.jsx)

Any help would be appreciated even simplifying my code. :)

Comment: Hello! You can use https://codesandbox.io/s/new to create a working demo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`<Widget>`](https://github.com/BlazingIsFire/Trello-Clone2/blob/main/src/App.js#L43) element receives the `parentCallback2` prop:

`<Widget key={i} parentCallback2={this.handleCallback}/>`

But it doesn't then pass it forward to `<Todobox>` [here](https://github.com/BlazingIsFire/Trello-Clone2/blob/main/src/App.js#L7) `const Widget = () => <Todobox />;`

so when `<Todobox>` tries to [invoke `parentCallback2`](https://github.com/BlazingIsFire/Trello-Clone2/blob/main/src/Todobox.jsx#L43) it throws the error since it's `undefined`

---

```
const Widget = ({parentCallback2}) => <Todobox parentCallback2={parentCallback2}/>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked great! Now just gotta work on passing more data through lol.